# Creating a instance, virtual on HP cloud or any Openstack Cloud using c#

Tags: c#, .net, openstack

I am using the below code to create a instance in the hp cloud(or any openstack). I am having issues with determining the base url.There could be other errors and i would appreciate anybody seeing them also. So do i find out the base url. I had a look through the hp docs but to no avail ?! Also i am unsure of how to obtain the image id, i presume the flavor is 'small' etc?

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using net.openstack.Core.Domain;
using net.openstack.Providers.Rackspace;


namespace Openstack2
{
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Uri baseUrl = new Uri("https://horizon.hpcloud.com/auth/login/");
        CloudIdentity cloudId = new CloudIdentity()
        {
            Username = "#####",
            Password = "####"
        };
        CloudIdentityProvider cip = new CloudIdentityProvider(cloudId, baseUrl);
        UserAccess ua = cip.Authenticate(cloudId);

        CloudServersProvider provider = new CloudServersProvider(cloudId);

        Metadata metaData = new Metadata(); // Add some metadata just because we can
        metaData.Add("Description", "Example 4 - Getting Started");

        string serverName = "Server a14";
        string imageId = "###";
        string flavorId = "standard.xsmall";

        NewServer newServer = provider.CreateServer(serverName, imageId, flavorId,DiskConfiguration.Manual, metaData);
    }
}
```

}

The above code is based on the rackspace sdk to connect to the hp cloud, so that could be an issue. But i also used the following code based on the other .net openstack api.:

```
var identityUrl = "https://horizon.hpcloud.com/auth/login/";
    var imageUrl = "http://server:9292";
    var username = "####";
    var password = "###";

    var cloudId = new CloudIdentity() { Username = username, Password = password };
    var cloudIdProvider = new CloudIdentityProvider(new Uri(identityUrl));

    cloudIdProvider.Authenticate(cloudId);

    var cloudServersProvider = new CloudServersProvider(cloudId, cloudIdProvider);

    var newServer = cloudServersProvider.CreateServer("Team 101 Server a14", "Team 101 Server a14", "standard.xsmall");
```

Still will not connect to my hp openstack. I think i will half to ditch c# and maybe go with powershell or nova.

Comment: Well i found the base url. It is listed in service api endpoints which is under user roles and api endpoints which is under the account name. Now i need the image ids. Seems i will have to write another program or introduce some lines code above to

Comment: Updated my post. Basically i cannot connect using either code samples at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

i am using HP Cloud and this is how i get the baseUrl:

```
...
using HPCloud.Common;
using HPCloud.Objects;
using HPCloud.Objects.Utility;
using HPCloud.Objects.DataAccess;
using HPCloud.Objects.Domain;
using HPCloud.Objects.Domain.Compute;
using HPCloud.Objects.Domain.Admin;

session = Session.CreateSession("accessKey", "secretKey", "tennantID");
private Session session = null;
    public static string GenerateUrl(Session session, string bucket_name, string key)
    {
        string baseUrl = session.Context.ServiceCatalog.GetService(HPCloud.Objects.Domain.Admin.Services.ObjectStorage).Url;
        return baseUrl + "/" + bucket_name + "/" + key;
    }
```

You will need to get accesskey, secretkey, and tennantID from your cloud admin page.

You may need to add HPCloud-API and BouncyCastle from Nuget.

so now you can use the following to drop a file in your cloud bucket:

```
public static bool PutFile(Session session, string bucket_name, string file_path, out string key)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(file_path))
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(file_path);
        }

        bool success = false;
        key = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file_path);
        try
        {
            var soRepo = session.Factory.CreateStorageObjectRepository();
            string fullUrl = GenerateUrl(session, bucket_name, key);
            soRepo.Copy(file_path, fullUrl, false);
            success = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            success = false;
            key = string.Empty;
        }
        return success;
    }
```